# What to do if Processing won't find a library?

Tags: css-float, processing, usage-statistics

No matter what I do, Processing just won't find this library. No matter where I put it or how many renames I do, Processing can't find it and I can't find an alternative anywhere. I basically only need it for the "Descriptive" class. And I know its in the correct spot because I have the library "minim" and Processing can find that. [The DL link](http://adilapapaya.com/papayastatistics/).

Anyone want to give it a shot and then give a solution (or walkthrough of what/how they did) if they find whats wrong? Or know of another library where this class is at?

Comment: Please don't add tags (such as `statistics`) that have nothing to do with your question and please provide enough information for others to reproduce the problem. This question is too vague to answer definitively (although Catherine's suggestions below might help).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you are putting the library in the wrong folder, click `Preferences` in Processing and look for `Sketchbook Location` (which is where you should copy the downloaded folder in) to make sure you are putting it in the right place. I have checked the download link and the site says you have to copy the **entire unzipped folder** into your `libraries` folder (which is located in your sketchbook folder) in order for it to work.

If you have checked what I suggested above and still cannot find a problem, refer to https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/How-to-Install-a-Contributed-Library which will hopefully help you.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to load a non-standard library into a Processing sketch is to **drag the `.jar` file onto the Processing editor.**

You don't have to install the library in the libraries directory. Just find a file like `YourLibrary.jar` and drag it directly onto your sketch in the Processing editor.

This will automatically put the library jar file in the correct place, and you'll be able to use the jar in your sketch.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/libraries) is a guide on using libraries in Processing.